# Jump every X instructions

Tags: c, assembly

I need to keep track of the quantity of work done by some programs, inside a single thread. To do that I would like to have minimum impact on the (c) code. Is there a way to trigger some piece of code every X instructions ?

I was thinking about adding the check at compile time, every X instructions. That would be ok inside a branch, but would (without a in depth branch analysis) requires a check at every jump ... In programs with many jumps it would be very costly.

Is there any tool/technique that allows to analyse the branches of the code (at compilation) so the checks are placed at even places ?

Comment: What is cost estimate of the check (is it 10 instructions or 1000)? How often do you want to check it (what is X)? Why not use `gdb` with `stepi`? (it will slowdown the program..)

Comment: That would be in the nominal way of running, so the solution must be as light as possible. So that would be more every 1000 or more instructions. (and no gdb)

Comment: What you're asking for is unrealistic without a CPU that does the work. In theory a compiler's assembler could keep track for you but since most functions have multiple code paths, I don't think you're going to see this any time soon. Instead, I think you'd be better off using OS-specific functions that keep track of CPU time allocated to each thread.

Comment: Have you considered using a profiler? Perfsuite (http://perfsuite.ncsa.illinois.edu/) is a free profiler, I personally prefer Intel VTune though. They will make use of special CPU registers which are designed exactly for this purpose - counting how often an instruction is called and how long it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably no other solutions than :

- using a separate thread,
- checking the number of cycles at each branch

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at doing this another way, i.e. using a profiler or CPU accounting.

If you are using Linux, then bizarrely enough, the POSIX mandated standard for `times()` doesn't (or at least didn't) do what it is meant to, and in fact gives (or gave) per thread accounting data:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/times.html

essentially as Linux threads *are* processes under the hood. That might be useful to you.

(apologies this isn't a direct answer but it was too long for a comment)

Comment: For measuring I use __rdtsc(), it seems like the best tool for x86

Comment: Won't that measure elapsed time (i.e. wall clock time) rather than time spent in the thread?

Comment: From wikipedia: "It counts the number of cycles since reset"

Comment: I think we are talking at cross purposes. Yes, it counts the number of CPU cycles from reset. However, OP wanted to see the number of CPU cycles actually spent executing *that thread*. The scheduler may use the CPU core concerned for other threads during the time. For example, `__rdtsc` will increment even if the thread executes `sleep(100)`, even though during the sleep the thread is not using any CPU cycles as it will not be scheduled.

Comment: Oh, you are the OP! Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes you are right it is an absolute time, but it is okay in my case (affinity is set and there is no sleep() and no concurrent thread)